# Import Bootstrap in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am struggling when I'm importing this Bootstrap. [Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwhkU.png).

I already did `npm i boostrap jquery popper.js`. But when I’m importing these, I’m getting an error.

This is my import from the *main.js* file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: I suggest you to use the one specially made for vue https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs

Answer (score 1):

As the others suggested, you can use bootstrap for Vue, but this does not work well for me. What I usually do is simply add the bootstrap cnd link to my index.html header

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: What happens if the connection is broken or jsdelivr is down? I prefer to install the packages or import the files directly into the project. Besides, if your own internet connection fails, you can work with your local bootstrap files as always. But yes - you are right.

Comment: @wittgenstein To be honest, I don't know. I've never had a problem with this approach, but I struggled a lot with the bootstrap-vue one. It is definitely not the nicest way of doing it, but it is the one that works the best for me.

Comment: The fact that you never had the problem says nothing about the existence of the problem. In almost any case, your solution will be fine.

Comment: thx for cdn solution, Im kinda new for bs-vue. thats why im prefer "normal" bs

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use Bootstrap in Vue.js, but you can use [bootstrap-vue](http://bootstrap-vue.org) or only Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Not true at all, bootstrap 5 no longer needs JQuery. You can use Bootstrap 5 without limitations with vue.
Have a look here: https://dev.to/codeply/using-bootstrap-5-with-vue-js-5fnp

Answer (score 0):

Cannot use JS part of bootstrap. But you can use part of css.

Install:

```
npm i bootstrap
npm i bootstrap-icons
```

main.js:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css'
```